# Check PDO query for result and then reuse the data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PDO, and am in the process of upgrading an application from mysql_query to PDO. This is surely a stupid question - but I hope someone can help me wrap my head around it.

I need to see if a PDO query has any data:
- if it doesn't, throw an error
- if it does, retrieve that data

I could do this easily with mysql_num_rows, but that's deprecated as we all know.

The issue is that once I've checked if there is any data, I can no longer retrieve it.

The check runs fine, but then when trying to retrieve the actual result, it's empty. I can of course execute the query again after the check - but I'd rather avoid having to run a query twice.

```
try
{
    $result = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = :email;");
    $result->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetchAll();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
        $error = 'Error fetching user: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo $error;
        exit();
}

if (!$data) {
    echo "No data!";
} else {
    echo "Data found!";
}           

$row = $result->fetch();
    echo "First name: " . $row['first_name'];
```

How can I solve this?
I tried to assign $result to another variable ($test = $result), and then run the data check on the $test variable instead - but even so, the $result variable STILL doesn't return any data after running the check (see the commented lines):

```
try
{
    $result = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = :email;");
    $result->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $result->execute();
    $test = $result; // Duplicating the variable
    $data = $test->fetchAll(); // Running the check on the duplicated variable
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
        $error = 'Error fetching user: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo $error;
        exit();
}

if (!$data) {
    echo "No data!";
} else {
    echo "Data found!";
}           

$row = $result->fetch(); // Still doesn't return the result!
    echo "First name: " . $row['first_name'];
```

This is really doing my head in... I think there's a simple solution somewhere, I just can't see it. Please help!

Comment: You have already retrieved all of the data when you used `fetchAll` so there is nothing left to retrieve when you try to use `fetch`. `fetchAll` will be an array which may contain one or more rows of data (since your query didn't limit the result to 1 row).

Comment: You might also want to use `$data = $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC):`. in order to return only an associative array with your colum names. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) for more information

Comment: Just as an FYI you may pass your variable directly in the execute call and avoid a separate call to bind. `$result->execute([':email'=>$email]);`

Comment: The PDO equivalent of `mysql_num_rows()` is `$result->rowCount()`

Comment: Assigning objects to different variables doesn't make a copy, so anything you do to one variable affects the other. Only arrays get copied, not objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result->fetch()` only fetches rows that haven't already been fetched. Since you fetched everything with `$result->fetchAll()`, there's nothing left.

If you want the first row, you can use:

```
$row = data[0];
```

If you want to process all the rows, use:

```
foreach ($data as $row)
```

Instead of fetching everything, you can use the `rowCount()` method.

```
if (!$result->rowCount()) {
    echo "No data";
} else {
    echo "Data found!";
}
```

There are caveats regarding the use of `rowCount()` with `SELECT` queries in PDO, but I think it generally works with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a `try/catch` block you can raise your own exceptions as well as catch those thrown by PDO - so you could do something like this:

```
try{

    $sql='SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = :email;';
    $stmt = $pdo2->prepare( $sql );

    if( !$stmt )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement');
    $result=$stmt->execute( array( ':email' => $email ) );

    if( !$result )throw new Exception('Failed to get any results');
    $rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if( $rows == 0 )throw new Exception('Empty recordset');

    while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
        echo $rs->firstname;
    }

}catch ( PDOException $e ){
    exit( 'Error fetching user: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always fetch individual rows and for the first row, check if the data is returned and process if not.  Then enter a `do...while()` loop which processes the data and then reads the next row at the end of the loop...

```
try
{
    $result = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = :email;");
    $result->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();  // Fetch first row of data

    if (!$row) {
        echo "No data!";
    } else {
        echo "Data found!";

        do { 
            echo "First name: " . $row['first_name'];
        }
        while ($row = $result->fetch());
    }           
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
        $error = 'Error fetching user: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo $error;
        exit();
}
```